# AttributeError: module 'google.cloud' has no attribute 'logging' Google Cloud

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, pycharm, google-authentication

I followed [these](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/core/auth.html) [tutorials](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python) from GCP.

But when I run the code, I get this error:

> `client = google.cloud.logging.Client() AttributeError: module 'google.cloud' has no attribute 'logging'`

I dont understand why since with `pyCharm` it shows me the method

My Code:

```
import unittest
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv(verbose=True)
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import google.cloud.logging


import unit_test
script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, os.getenv('FIREBASE_ADMIN_CREDENTIAL_PATH'))
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    file_path)

client = google.cloud.logging.Client()
```

The File path:
[image]

Comment: Are you running from pycharm? If so, please point the [Pycharm interpeter](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html) to the Python environment which has installed this library

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the `google-cloud-logging` package in either your local environment or add it to your `requirements.txt` depending on where you're trying to run the code:

Install it locally:

```
pip install --upgrade google-cloud-logging
```

Or add to `requirements.txt`

```
google-cloud-logging
```